# RegExp in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that in ElasticSearch we can query using regex. 
But is it possible to store regex in a field of elasticsearch?

Example:

Suppose I have 2 columns in my csv:column1;column2

and a raw A:  '`action';'work(s|ing)?'`

When I want to have all the raws where column2 matchs the word 'works', I should get the raw A

Comment: can you show the ES schema?

Comment: I am a beginner in ES, I am not sure I have understood your question.

I had a csv file with 2 columns (type:string). I used logstash to upload it into ES. So now I have my data in one index named: 'instance1'

Comment: What is teh column names in ES ?

Comment: 'type' ; 'verb'

Comment: "date_formats": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },  something like this.

Comment: seems close. I will read the documentation of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not possible in ES to do so.

Fuzzy query solve my problem and it works well.